# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки стиралось то что в поле html

Tags: python, html, flask

Я сделал поле для ввода и кнопку отправить. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, я стирал то что в поле. Как это сделать?

Если надо, пишу на python на flask

```
<input type="text" size="40"/>

<p>
    <input type="submit",value='Отправить'>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полю, которое нужно очищать следует присвоить аттрибут id:

```html
<input id="field-0" type="text" size="40"/>
```

А на событие нажатия кнопки повесить скрипт, который будет очищать поле ввода:

```
<p>
    <input type="submit" value='Отправить' onclick="document.querySelector('.field-0').value=''">
</p>
```

Полностью форма будет такой:

```
<input id="field-0" type="text" size="40"/>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value='Отправить' onclick="document.querySelector('#field-0').value=''">
</p>
```

Comment: а откуда этот скрипт взять? а то я тупо скопировал, не сработало xD

Comment: Была опечатка, исправил, должно работать